# Bootstrap 3, change icon upon collapse

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I use Bootstrap 3 framework and I need to change icon upon collapsing the element. I tried below solution but I cant really make it work. Please, any ideas?

**That's my HTML code:**

```
<div id="categories-sidebar">
  <a href="#categories" data-toggle="collapse"><i class="nav-arrows pe-7s-angle-down fz32 pe-va"></a>
</div>

<div id="categories" class="collapse">Some text here</div>
```

and I'm trying to change the icon with below jQuery code?

```
$('#categories').on('shown.bs.collapse', function() {
    $(".nav-arrows").addClass('pe-7s-angle-up').removeClass('pe-7s-angle-down');
  });

$('#categories').on('hidden.bs.collapse', function() {
    $(".nav-arrows").addClass('pe-7s-angle-down').removeClass('pe-7s-angle-up');
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

The only issue I can see here that might be causing this is that your `<i>` tag is not being closed with an `</i>`. This might be causing enough of a problem to stop your icons working altogether.

I've made an example using your code that works fine

```js
$('#categories').on('show.bs.collapse', function() {
    $(".nav-arrows").addClass('glyphicon-chevron-up').removeClass('glyphicon-chevron-down');
  });

$('#categories').on('hide.bs.collapse', function() {
    $(".nav-arrows").addClass('glyphicon-chevron-down').removeClass('glyphicon-chevron-up');
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div id="categories-sidebar">
  <a href="#categories" data-toggle="collapse"><i class="nav-arrows glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down fz32 pe-va"></i> text</a>
</div>

<div id="categories" class="collapse">Some text here</div>
```

The only changes I made were:

- Use the built in Glyphicons (since I don't have access to your icons)
- Add the word 'text' next to the icon, just so I could click it
  easier!
- Made the toggling happen on `hide` and `show` as this is
  slightly more responsive.